# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've recently got stuck proving that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-2)$. I understand that the definitions of two rings are
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] &= \{a + b \sqrt{2} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \}, \\ 
\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-2) &= \{c(x^2-2)\mid c \in \mathbb{Z} \}.
\end{align*}
Did I understand the definitions correctly? Then what should I do to proceed?
Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Use the first isomorphism theorem for rings. Take the evaluation map $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ that sends $X$ to $\sqrt{2}$. What is its kernel? What is its image?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-2) = \Bbb{Z}+x\Bbb{Z}$, not too hard to find the kernel of the homomorphism to $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$

Comment: Your definition of ${\mathbb Z}[x]/(x^2 - 2)$ is wrong. Its elements are residu classes modulo $x^2 - 2$; you can think of them as polynomials of the form $a x + b$ and when multiplying two of those polynomials, reduce the product again to this form by using $x^2 = 2$.

Comment: @Albert: Thanks for the comment.  I am thinking like this: Consider the ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. Quotient the LHS by $x^2-2$. By the First Isomorphism Theorem $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\text{ker}\phi \cong \text{im} \phi$, where $\text{ker}\phi = \{x \mid \phi(x^2-2)=0\}$ and $\text{im}\phi = \{\phi(x) \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \}$. Is that argument correct?

Comment: @reuns: Is $\text{ker}\phi = \{x \mid \phi(x^2-2)=0\}$?

Comment: @Magdiragdag. You're right. Thanks!